# Getting a time difference across timezones with moment-timezone

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I am given a string representing a time, and a timezone ID.  I need to determine whether the time in question occurs within the next half hour, but the computer I'm running on is in a different timezone than the one where the string was captured.  Minor note: it's OK (still happensSoon === true) if the event happened in the past).  Just trying to distinguish things which happen more than a half hour in the future from the rest.

This seems like it ought to be straightforward, but I'm getting nowhere with it.

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

const hm = s => moment(s).format('HH:mm')

const happensSoon = (then, timezoneId) => {
  console.log(`then:`, then)             // 2018-10-04T16:39:52-07:00
  console.log(`timezoneId:`, timezoneId) // America/New_York
  const localNow = moment()
    .clone()
    .tz(timezoneId)
  const localThen = moment(then)
    .clone()
    .tz(timezoneId)
  const diff = localThen.diff(localNow, 'minutes')
  console.log(`localThen:`, hm(localThen)) // 19:39
  console.log(`localNow:`, hm(localNow))   // 16:24
  console.log(`then:`, hm(then))           // 16:39
  console.log(`diff:`, diff)               // 194
  return diff <= 30
}
```

Running in "America/Los_Angeles" timezone.  My "local" is intended to represent the New York time.  So, 16:39 is the input value for `then` and I expect the comparison to be around that time (Oh, I'm running this at about 13:20 developer-local time).  So, basically, in the code above, I want to be comparing 16:39 with 16:20, big-apples-to-big-apples.  I don't want to hack my way into this; I want a solution I understand.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job for me:

```
const happensSoon = (then, timezoneId) => {
  const thenThere = moment.tz(then, timezoneId)
  const nowThere = moment().tz(timezoneId)
  const diff = thenThere.diff(nowThere, 'minutes')
  return diff <= 30
}
```

Given a time string `then` without timezone information and a `timezoneId`, it creates a moment at that time and timezone, then creates a new moment and translates it to the same timezone, then diffs them.